# Three.js model, joint not responding to rotation/posiiton command line

Tags: javascript, three.js

//snippet of code below, obviously i'm missing something, but struggling to find any guidance on what. attempting to rotate a parent joint, so that its children (eg. leg, foot) rotates with it. adding the code to the hip appears to do nothing.

//I can only rotate the leg itself, which I don't believe is the correct way to go about it.

```
Hip = new THREE.Object3D();
Hip.name = "Hip";
scene.add(Hip);
Hip.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2; //this doesnt rotate the joint?


Hip.add(Leg); //adds child (leg) to parent (hip)

// Leg 
Leg = createLeg(); //called from a function that returns a custom shape
Leg.name = "Leg";
scene.add(Leg);
```

Comment: Any warnings or error messages in the browser console?

Comment: the only error, which I don't think is related is: Error: WebGL warning: Disallowing antialiased backbuffers due to blacklisting.